# Can European bought games work on an American Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, region-lock

I live in Europe and I have an American console so can I buy games over here and would they work on this console? Or is it region locked? And second, if I do buy games overseas, can the language be switched to english? Or since it is a German game would it automatically be put in German?

Comment: Be careful with language. Many games only contain a set amount of languages on disc. Especially larger games only contain at most half-a dozen languages on disc. In the past, this was true for Oblivion and Morrowind which only played in French when bought in France or Luxembourg. However, today you will most likely be able to buy language packs. Not sure all games offer them but some to. HAve a look before you buy.

Answer (score 2):

The console and games are completely region-free. You can set your locale and language in the console's options and from there you're good to go.

You can find the settings here:

1. Guide button on the controller
2. Settings
3. System Settings
4. Console Settings
5. Language and Locale

The only limitation are countries where Xbox Live is currently not supported. You can only play or get games which require Xbox Live if you're using Locale settings of supported countries.

[Click](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/countries) for a list of supported countries.